# Maps in Lists in Maps

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

After much trial and error, I am at a loss as to how to deal with embedded lists and maps in Dart and furthermore, how they can be accessed via Polymer data binding.  The objective is to read a JSON file and build an HTML table that can be filtered and sorted.  (I just hard coded map data below for clarity.)

I can build an HTML table within my Polymer element (see buildTable) as long as the Map looks like testMap3 seen in the Dart code below and it renders fine with:

HTML:

```
<p><b>The data from testMap3 after building table in Dart file:</b>/p> 
<table class="bordered" id="dataTable"></table>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this via Polymer data binding.  Right now I am just dumping the k-v pairs, just so that I can see the objects:

HTML:

```
<p><b>The data from testMap3 via Polymer binding:</b></p> 
<template repeat="{{key in testMap.keys}}">
  <p>{{key}} : {{testMap[key]}}</p>   
</template>
```

**How can I use data binding to create a table that would match the result of the first example above?  And to make things more difficult, how can I do so using testMap2 instead?**

Dart:

Rendering testMap3 works fine when calling buildTable:

```
Map testMap3 = toObservable({
                'columns' : ["First Name", "Attending", "Phone"],
                'rows' : [{'First Name' : "Alice", 
                           'Attending' : "Yes",
                           'Phone' : "555-1212"},                              
                          {'First Name' : "Bob", 
                           'Attending' : "Yes",
                           'Phone' : "555-2323"}                              
                         ]
           });
```

Iterating through testMap2 has been problematic given the additional embedded 'Phone' value is a list containing another map:

```
 Map testMap2 = toObservable({
               'columns' : ["First Name", "Attending", "Phone"],
               'rows' : [{'First Name' : "Alice", 
                          'Attending' : "Yes",
                          'Phone' : [{'Home' : "555-1234",
                                      'Work' : "555-4321",
                                      'Mobile' : "555-1212"}]},                              
                         {'First Name' : "Bob", 
                          'Attending' : "Yes",
                          'Phone' : [{'Home' : "555-2345",
                                      'Work' : "555-5432",
                                      'Mobile' : "555-2323"}]}                            
                        ]
          });
```

The following code works fine for testMap3 but nothing I have tried lets me loop through the phone data if I use testMap2.  **Any ideas on how I can do this?**

```
buildTable() {

  TableElement table = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#dataTable");
  table.children.clear();

  TableSectionElement tBody = table.createTBody();

  TableSectionElement tHead = table.createTHead();
  TableRowElement trh = tHead.addRow();

  for (var column in testMap3["columns"]) {
    var cell = new Element.tag('th');
    cell.text = column;
    trh.append(cell);
  }

  for (var row in testMap3["rows"]) {

    TableRowElement tr = tBody.addRow();
    for (var column in testMap3["columns"]) {
      tr.addCell().text = row[column];       
    }
  }   
}
```

Finally, one of the ultimate goals is to filter all the columns in the rendered table taking an approach similar to the following...is this doable?  I can't seem to find examples using Maps or even Lists within Lists.

HTML:

```
<template repeat="{{city in listOfCities | filter(searchParameter)}}">
  <li>{{city}}</li>
</template>
```

Dart:

```
@observable List listOfCities = ["Chicago", "New York", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", "Denver"];

filter(term) => (listOfCities) => term.isEmpty ? listOfCities : listOfCities.where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(searchParameter.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated as I have been banging my head for over a week and am just about ready to give up.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example table  output HTML doesn't actually seemed to be included

Comment: Just using the id="dataTable"  seems to work because of the line in the Dart code:  
        TableElement table = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#dataTable");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Polymer databinding will work for testMap3:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td template repeat="{{column in testMap3['columns']}}">{{column}}</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr template repeat="{{row in testMap3['rows']}}">
      <td template repeat="{{data in row.keys}}">{{row[data]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Filtering on table rows could be accomplished with the following method:

```dart
filter(term) => (rows) => term.isEmpty
      ? rows
      : rows.where((row) => row.values.any((val) => val.toLowerCase().contains(term)));
```

It looks through the entire row data and matches each column against the search term.

The tbody would then look like this:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr template repeat="{{row in testMap3['rows'] | filter(search)}}">
    <td template repeat="{{data in row.keys}}">{{row[data]}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And it assumes you have a text input that hooks up to a String value named `search`.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything worked great!  I really don't need to use the data structure in testMap2 so I will just revise things to not go one level deeper.  Seeing the answer makes me kick myself for not asking earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th template repeat="{{item in testMap3['columns']}}">{{item}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr template repeat="{{row in testMap3['rows']}}">
      <td template repeat="{{key in testMap3['columns']}}">{{row[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the

```
<tr template repeat="...">
```

is the same as

```
<template repeat="...">
```

but you can't use <template> within a table, so you're forced to use

```
<tr template repeat="...">
```

Sorry I don't know why it has to be done this way, you'd have to do your own research on that.  It will throw an error if you try to do it using

```
<table>
    <template repeat="...">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </template>
</table>
```

as <template> is not allowed inside the table elements.

As for filtering

you could do this

```
@observable String search = '';

filter(search) => (List row) =>
    row.where((item) => item['Phone'].contains(search));
```

for filtering based upon phone

or filter for any value that matches the search string

```
filter(String search) => (List row) =>
    row.where((Map item) => item.values.any((val) => val.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())));
```

which is similar to the other answer from @pixel-elephant

Comment: Thank you!  Everything you show worked great, with just a slight difference on the filtering as you stated.